# Running multiple screen commands with crontab and log them separately, giving each a separate screen name

Tags: cron, logs, gnu-screen

How can I log the output of multiple screen sessions which are executed by `crontab` separately? Currently I am running them in

```
screen -dm -L command
```

style in `crontab` but it logs all the sessions to `screenlog.0` file.

In relation to that, how shall I format the command line for `crontab` so that I can name each screen session?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [screen man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html), you'll note that right under the `-L` option is the `-Logfile` option:

```
   -Logfile file
        By default logfile name is "screenlog.0". You can set new
        logfile name with the "-Logfile" option.
```

Setting that to a unique file for each cron task should get you what you want.

You can set a session name using the `-S <name>` option.

Your command line might look like:

```
screen -dm -L -S session1 -Logfile session1.log
```

You could attach to that session by running:

```
screen -x session1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you also know how I should name the sessions? I mean, what would be the correct syntax if I wanted to name each session run by Crontab differently? Also, out of curiosity, is it possible to name the log files parametrically with screen? (e.g. based on the date/hour)

Comment: I think you should name the sessions whatever you want. I don't know what you're doing so I don't have any suggestions.  I don't think `screen` has any support for parametric naming of files, but since cron tasks are executed by a shell you should just do something like `-Logfile /path/to/my/log-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log` to interpolate the date into the filename.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, what I meant to ask was, if I wanted to name it from the crontab, should the correct syntax for crontab be "screen -dm  -Logfile /path/to/my/log-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log -S name_for_session command_to_run"

Comment: That looks reasonable. What happens if you try it?

Comment: For some reason I haven't figured out, the Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS instance keeps giving an error "Error: Unknown option Logfile"

Comment: Hey, voter, I would love a comment to go along with that downvote. I am beginning to suspect you're someone with a personal gripe. Let me know how I can help!